# finding availability zone with IP or HOSTNAME

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm working for personal project that communicates data with a public service that's running on AWS.

I'd like to minimize data transfer payment by locating my server (EC2 instance) on a same region / availability zone where the public service locates.

For example, let's say the public service is AAA. And, I found that AAA's server is located in us-west-1 region. But, I don't know its availability zone information. How can I find the availability zone information of service AAA? Assuming I know IP address of AAA server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible... but it also doesn't matter.

EC2 data transfer pricing within a region does not change based on whether resources are in the same availability zone, unless both of these conditions are true:

- machines must be in the same VPC, and
- machines must be communicating using private IP addresses

If using EIPs or public IPs or private IPs with VPC peering, the data transfer charges within the region are the same whether or not the availability zone is also the same, so your costs are unrelated to specific availability zone placement.

For completeness, I'll note that there is an an exception for traffic between load balancers and the instances attached to them (not applicable here) and an apparent exception for IPv6 traffic within the same VPC (also not applicable).

If you are working on a personal project, consider using Lightsail rather than EC2, since Lightsail instances include a [generious bandwidth allowance](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/).